# Do concurrent connections to an HTTPS website perform separate SSL handshakes?

Tags: tls, http, tcp

I know that most browsers nowadays support around 6 concurrent TCP sessions per hostname, to perform multiple requests at the same time.

For sites which utilise SSL, is there a separate handshake performed for each TCP session, or is a single SSL handshake performed, with the resulting symmetric key being reused for each concurrent TCP session?

Comment: This isn't a security question, it's a protocol question.  You should be asking over in StackOverflow.

Comment: @SteveSether While that may be true, I'm inclined to believe that people who have questions about SSL that aren't code-related will come here. In fact, this question would probably be closed on SO. SuperUser might be the better place? It's a gray-area question...

Comment: SO is really limited then if they'd reject that question.  It really needs to be broken out into multiple groups.  There really needs to be a web development group specifically for the web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each new connection does a separate TCP handshake and a separate TLS handshake. But if there is an existing SSL session they will try to reuse it, so all but the first connection to a server only do an [abbreviated handshake](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html) if the server supports session reuse. In case of session reuse no key exchange is performed, that is the same symmetric key is re-used. See also [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work).